# CORS только в FireFox. Причина?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Всем привет.
Столкнулся с проблемой CORS.
Имеется проект на микрофронтах.
Все развернуто на одном сервере на разных портах.
98 порт для Root приложения, в котором есть importmap с путями к собранным js файлам остальных фронтендов. На 97 порту проблемный фронтенд.
После развертки проектов. Все работает через IE, Opera и GoogleChrome.
Только через FireFox. Возникает CORS при GET запросе на порт 98.
С такими заголовками:

```
Accept
    */*
Accept-Encoding
    gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language
    ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Connection
    keep-alive
Host
    x.x.x.x:98
Origin
    https://x.x.x.x:97
Referer
    https://x.x.x.x:97/
Sec-Fetch-Dest
    script
Sec-Fetch-Mode
    cors
Sec-Fetch-Site
    same-site
User-Agent
    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0
```

CORS на бэкенде настроены.
И по идее проблем быть не должно.
Что не так?

```
     services.AddCors(options =>
 {
     options.AddPolicy(corsPolicy, policy =>
     {
         policy
             .AllowAnyMethod()
             .AllowAnyHeader()
             .AllowCredentials()
             .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)
     });
 });
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что сервер отвечает, какими заголовками? Access-Control-Allow-Origin заголовок есть? Что содержит? OPTIONS запрос приходит перед GET? Попробуйте открыть инструменты разработчика и выключить кеш на вкладке Сеть, после чего обновить страницу.

Comment: @aepot OPTIONS запроса нет перед GET.
Я прикрепил к концу поста скриншот вкладки Сеть.
Кеш там я тоже отключал - результат не меняется

Comment: @aepot полистал запросы через Хром. Там OPTIONS отправляется только с сервису авторизации. Но и в GET запросе заголовки отличаются. Тоже прикрепил

Answer (score 1):

Firefox единственный браузер который кеширует CORS ответ, и этот кеш невозможно очистить. Это задокументированная но не исправленная проблема https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1528603

То есть если один единственный раз вы получили в ответ запрещенный CORS - теперь даже когда вы разрешите его - Firefox будет блокировать ресурс всегда.

Потому для исключения что именно кеш - источник проблемы - попробуйте с другого компьютера, где ранее этот сайт с Firefox не запрашивался.

Comment: Добавлю что в следующий раз при запросе на сайт можно указать заголовки Cache-Control и Expires на стороне сервера, чтобы указать браузеру что не нужно хранить кэш. Хотя порой такое не рекомендуется.

Answer (score 1):

- Тестируем удобно через [CORS Everywhere](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/).
- `[Ctrl]`+`[5]` - чистим кэш **запросов**, но если **кэшированы** ресурсы, то какие заголовки Вы ждёте?

> [Update: Mozilla has a limit of 24 hours: http://monsur.hossa.in/2012/09/07/thoughts-on-the-cors-preflight-cache.html (the line number he links to is out-of-date; it's 844 now). Also looking through the code he references, it looks like it will be cleared when the browser closes, but there is no other way to clear it. I could be mistaken though.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815842/how-to-check-content-of-preflight-result-cache-in-firefox); Stackoverflow

Из ответа - 24 часа для чистки.

Comment: Вы дальше ответ прочитайте, там написано что 24 - это устаревшая инфа

Comment: C CORS Everywhere пробовал. Не загружается

Comment: А у Вас расширение красного цвета было (CORS был отключён на тот момент)?

Comment: @niknils зеленого :)